# How do we calculate the output image sizes

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

We have an input image of size 80 x 100, then we apply 5 x 5 convolution filter to this image and it gives a map of activations at 76 x 96. Then, we apply a 2 x 2 pooling and it gives a map of pooled activations at 38 x 48. How do we find the output image sizes 76 x 96 and 38 x 48?

Comment: I've tried to reword your question.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no padding, then we could only slide the filter to the right until its right edge touches the right boundary of the image. So, the filter first spans columns [1,5], then [2,6] and so on until [96,100]. So, the filter is multiplied with image patches 96 times for a single row. Similarly, we’ll have 76 rows in the output image. For a single dimension, the general formula is $I-F+1$ where $I$ is image size and $F$ is filter size.

After having an image size of 76x96, the pooling layer reduces each non-overlapping 2x2 patch of the image to a single number. So, along each dimension, the size is halved, and we have 38 x 48.